# Integration Issue with PhonePe Android SDK: ERROR_B2B_API_RETURNED_ERROR and {"success":false,"code":"401"}

Tags: android, kotlin, payment-gateway, payment, phonepe

Here is the documentation link Android SDK: https://developer.phonepe.com/v1/docs/android-pg-sdk-integration . I am trying to integrate phonepe Payment Gateway. When i tried to request payment I got this response In onActivityResult.E/onActivityResult4: key_error_code : ERROR_B2B_API_RETURNED_ERROR and {"success":false, "code":"401"}. What should be the next solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on flutter, it was due to bad input, I was giving wrong body and salt
the correct body and salt:

```
String getSalt() {
  String apiEndPoint = "/pg/v1/pay";
  var salt = "099eb0cd-02cf-4e2a-8aca-3e6c6aff0399";
  var index = 1;
  return sha256
          .convert(utf8.encode(getBody() + apiEndPoint + salt))
          .toString() +
      "###" +
      index.toString();
}

String getBody() {
  var body = {
    "merchantId": "PGTESTPAYUAT",
    "merchantTransactionId": "transaction_123",
    "merchantUserId": "90223250",
    "amount": 1000,
    "mobileNumber": "9999999999",
    "callbackUrl": "https://webhook.site/55d95b9b-bec9-491e-b257-cbaf0ff7aa7e",
    "paymentInstrument": {"type": "UPI_INTENT", "targetApp": "com.phonepe.app"},
    "deviceContext": {"deviceOS": "ANDROID"}
  }; // Encode the request body to JSON
  String jsonBody = jsonEncode(body);
  String base64EncodedBody = base64Encode(utf8.encode(jsonBody));
  return base64EncodedBody;
}
```